# Change scroll speed of one particular element plugins

Tags: javascript, scroll

Are there any plugins to change scroll speed of only a particular element like an image other than parallax ?
I want to change scroll speed of few elements on my webpage..

Comment: Google will be best to answer these kind of questions, here generally people ask for help on something they have already tried but still need expert advise.  (http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: yup..i have already done it using animate...but its not smooth...i came across many plugins but none of them is good enough...thats why i had to ask

Comment: Ok, this would be helpful? https://codepen.io/JTParrett/pen/BkDie